# NullPointerException with "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true )"?

Tags: java, android

I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.weslange.Term_Scheduling/com.weslange.Term_Scheduling.Term_ChangingDetails_Activity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   com.weslange.Term_Scheduling.TermData.getTermID()' on a null object
>   reference

The following seems to cause the issue:  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true )`

I know that "`getSupportActionBar()`" does work, because the following works just fine:  `getSupportActionBar().setTitle( "Selecting Courses" )`

MainActivity is the root parent.  "`Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.java`" is a child of that activity.  "`Term_CourseSelection_Activity.java`" is a child of "`Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.java`".  The first two work fine with "`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true )`".

I think the `NullPointerException` refers to a Parcelable in my "`Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.java`" file.  "`Term_CourseSelection_Activity.java`" contains the source of the exception, which occurs when "`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true )`" is present in that file.

I assume "`AndroidManifest.xml`" is correct, since everything works fine if I call "`finish()`" in "`Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.java`".

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT 01 :** (Adding MainActivity.java for clarity.)

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Term_RecyclerView_Adapter.ItemClickListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Term_RecyclerView_Adapter adapter;
    TermData test_TermData_Value;

    Database_Handling databaseHandling;
    List< TermData > termsArrayList;
    List< CourseData > coursesArrayList;
    List< MentorData > mentorsArrayList;
    List< AssessmentData > assessmentsArrayList;




    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );


        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        //This section ensures that each of the listings for the "Creation" activities begins with an example.
        databaseHandling = new Database_Handling( this );
        termsArrayList = databaseHandling.getAllTerms();
        coursesArrayList = databaseHandling.getAllCourses();
        mentorsArrayList = databaseHandling.getAllMentors();
        assessmentsArrayList = databaseHandling.getAllAssessments();


        if ( termsArrayList.isEmpty() ) {

            TermData termDataBeginning = new TermData();
            databaseHandling.addTermData( termDataBeginning );

            //This line is necessary for this class, since the "recyclerView" listing needs populating.
            termsArrayList = databaseHandling.getAllTerms();

        }


        if ( coursesArrayList.isEmpty() ) {

            CourseData courseDataBeginning = new CourseData();
            databaseHandling.addCourseData( courseDataBeginning );

        }


        if ( mentorsArrayList.isEmpty() ) {

            MentorData mentorDataBeginning = new MentorData();
            databaseHandling.addMentorData( mentorDataBeginning );

        }


        if ( assessmentsArrayList.isEmpty() ) {

            AssessmentData assessmentDataThing = new AssessmentData();
            databaseHandling.addAssessmentData( assessmentDataThing );

        }
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


        recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recyclerView_Array_in_XML );
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( this );


        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
                recyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation() );
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration( dividerItemDecoration );
        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( linearLayoutManager );

        adapter = new Term_RecyclerView_Adapter( this, termsArrayList);
        adapter.setClickListener( this );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );


        floatingActionButton = findViewById( R.id.floatingActionButton_Thing );
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {

                int newPosition = ( databaseHandling.getTermDataCount() + 1 );

                TermData termDataThing = new TermData();
                termDataThing.setTermID( newPosition );

                databaseHandling.addTermData( termDataThing );

                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                //Using this way to re-launch the current activity seems visually better than
                // "recreate()".
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menu_main, menu );

        return true;

    }


    //==============================================================================================
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
        if ( id == R.id.course_creation ) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, CourseCreation_Activity.class );
            startActivity( intent );

            return true;

        }
        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&


        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
        if ( id == R.id.mentor_creation ) {


            Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, MentorCreation_Activity.class );
            startActivity( intent );

            return true;

        }
        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&


        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
        if ( id == R.id.assessment_creation ) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, AssessmentCreation_Activity.class );
            startActivity( intent );

            return true;

        }
        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );

    }
    //==============================================================================================


    @Override
    public void onItemClick( View view, int position ) {

        //This prepares the "TermData" thing for entering info through "Term_ChangingDetails_Activity".
        Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.class );
        test_TermData_Value = adapter.getItem( position );

        intent.putExtra( "termData_Parcelable", test_TermData_Value );

        //This ships the info to "Term_ChangingDetails_Activity".
        startActivity( intent );

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        termsArrayList = databaseHandling.getAllTerms();

        //**************************************************************************
        adapter = new Term_RecyclerView_Adapter( this, termsArrayList);
        adapter.setClickListener( this );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );
        //**************************************************************************

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.java :

```
public class Term_ChangingDetails_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button saveButton;

    int termID;

    EditText termName_EditText;
    Button startingDate_Button;
    Button endingDate_Button;
    Button courseSelection_Button;

    Bundle dataArgument_Bundle_Example;
    DialogFragment startingDateFragment;
    DialogFragment endingDateFragment;

    TermData termData_TransferInfo;
    Database_Handling databaseHandling;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        //The below line is necessary for showing info at all.
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_term_changingdetails);

        databaseHandling = new Database_Handling( this );


        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final TermData termData_Values = intent.getParcelableExtra( "termData_Parcelable" );
        termID = termData_Values.getTermID();
        //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&


        //This displays a back button on the ToolBar at the top of the Activity.
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );

        //This just changes the title of the ToolBar.
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle( "Changing Term Info" );


        //*****************************************************************
        termName_EditText = findViewById( R.id.termNameXML );
        termName_EditText.setText( termData_Values.getTermName() );

        startingDate_Button = findViewById( R.id.startingDateButtonXML );
        startingDate_Button.setText( termData_Values.getStartingDate() );

        endingDate_Button = findViewById( R.id.endingDateButtonXML );
        endingDate_Button.setText( termData_Values.getEndingDate() );
        //*****************************************************************


        //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        saveButton = findViewById( R.id.saveButtonXML );
        saveButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {

            termData_TransferInfo = new TermData( termID,
                    termName_EditText.getText().toString(),
                    startingDate_Button.getText().toString(),
                    endingDate_Button.getText().toString() );

            databaseHandling.updateTermData( termData_TransferInfo );
            finish();

            }
        });
        //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


        //TODO START AN ACTIVITY FOR CHOOSING FROM A LIST OF COURSES.
        courseSelection_Button = findViewById( R.id.courseSelection_ButtonXML );
        courseSelection_Button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {

                Intent intent = new Intent( Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.this, Term_CourseSelection_Activity.class );
                startActivity( intent );

            }
        });

    }


    public void reveal_StartingDate_DatePicker( View v ) {

        startingDateFragment = new DatePickerFragment_TERM_StartingDate();
        startingDateFragment.setArguments( dataArgument_Bundle_Example );
        startingDateFragment.show( getFragmentManager(), "starting date picker" );

    }


    public void setStartingDate_in_StartingDate_Button( String startingDate_for_Button ) {

        startingDate_Button.setText( startingDate_for_Button );

    }


    public void reveal_EndingDate_DatePicker( View view ) {

        endingDateFragment = new DatePickerFragment_TERM_EndingDate();
        endingDateFragment.setArguments( dataArgument_Bundle_Example );
        endingDateFragment.show( getFragmentManager(), "ending date picker" );

    }


    public void setEndingDate_in_EndingDate_Button( String endingDate_for_Button ) {

        endingDate_Button.setText( endingDate_for_Button );

    }
}
```

Term_CourseSelection_Activity.java :

```
public class Term_CourseSelection_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button saveButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_term_courseselection );

        //This just changes the title of the ToolBar.
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle( "Selecting Courses" );





        //TODO  THE SOFTWARE WORKS FINE WHEN THIS PART IS REMOVED.  OTHERWISE, I GET A 'NullPointerException'.
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++        
        //This displays the "back" button.
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++





        saveButton = findViewById( R.id.saveButtonXML );
        saveButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {

                finish();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.weslange.Term_Scheduling.MainActivity"

    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Array_in_XML"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton_Thing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_term"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_term_changingdetails.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:showDividers="none"

    tools:context="com.weslange.Term_Scheduling.Term_ChangingDetails_Activity"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\nPlease Adjust as Necessary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/termNameXML"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startingDateButtonXML"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:onClick="reveal_StartingDate_DatePicker"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/endingDateButtonXML"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:onClick="reveal_EndingDate_DatePicker"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButtonXML"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Changes and Return to the Main List"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/courseSelection_ButtonXML"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Courses for This Term"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_term_courseselection.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.weslange.Term_Scheduling.Term_CourseSelection_Activity"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\nChoose the Courses for This Term"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButtonXML"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Changes and Return to the Term Details"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the setting on the support `ActionBar` is involved. The Exception seems to be thrown before you ever get to that line. `intent.getParcelableExtra( "termData_Parcelable" )` is returning null. Check that you're correctly attaching that extra with the right key in whichever `Activity` is starting `Term_ChangingDetails_Activity`.

Comment: Why do you think it is that line causing the issue? The error says it an attempt to call `getTermID()`: *"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.weslange.Term_Scheduling.TermData.getTermID() on a null object reference"*

Comment: If I remove, " `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true )` " from " _Term_CourseSelection_Activity.java_  ", then everything seems fine.  Calling " `finish()` " through a Button appears to achieve the same effect successfully without the NullPointerException.  Admittedly, I do not know how to trace back to a line number with the stack trace in Android Studio.  I am just basing on what seems to avoid the NullPointerException.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you're crashing when you actually use that `ActionBar` up button to go back to `Term_ChangingDetails_Activity`?

Comment: Yes.  It brings up a message that says " _Unfortunately, Term Scheduling has stopped._ ".  It returns to the _MainActivity_ at that point though, and the software continues to run despite the crash.  " _Term_ChangingDetails_Activity_ " and " _Term_CourseSelection_Activity_ " are the ones that stop, but they can be brought up again through MainActivity.  Sorry, if I am confusing.

Comment: OK, I think I'm following you, now. That up button, IIRC the details, is going to create a new up `Intent` – one without your extras on it – and start that to go "back". That's why you get that NPE when using the up button, but not when `finish()`ing. In your case, you don't want those Activities to be started without your `Intent`s and extras, so you should always `finish()`. If you want to still offer that up button, override the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method in the `Activity`, check if `item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home`, `finish()`, and `return true`, else return the `super` result.

Comment: I would also mention that it seems like you're starting these child Activities to gather data that the parent will need to be aware of. If that's so, you might instead use `startActivityForResult()`, and override `onActivityResult()` in the parents. Even if you don't directly pass back any data, the parent can know to refresh when `onActivityResult()` runs.

Comment: I totally forgot about " `startActivityForResult()` ".  Also, I appreciate the other information.  I will try them out, and if it goes well, I would definitely like to see you get credit.

Comment: @Mike M.  At least, " `finish()` " stops the crashing.  The other information points me in a good direction to follow from there.  If you care to provide an "answer", I will up-vote.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah, good to hear. I'd want to re-familiarize myself with the details of the up action first, before posting an answer, but I won't have time to get to that for a while. I'll make a note to myself, but if I forget, feel free to post an answer yourself, so you can close out your question. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: At least, I understand why the crashing happened now.  That will help me avoid the problem in the future and "down the road".  I am mixing your earlier suggestion of " `startActivityForResult()` " with the parent Activity and a couple of buttons for " `Activity.RESULT_OK` " and " `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` " for the moment in the child Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike M. provided the answer in the comments of the question, so he is deserving of the credit.  If you find this useful, please up-vote him.

A lack of " `finish()` " caused the crashing in " *Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.java* ".  It should have looked like this:

```
courseSelection_Button = findViewById( R.id.courseSelection_ButtonXML );
courseSelection_Button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick( View view ) {

        Intent intent = new Intent( Term_ChangingDetails_Activity.this, Term_CourseSelection_Activity.class );
        startActivity( intent );
        finish();

    }
});
```

While that stops the crashing, I am not sure why the "back" button failed. Adding " `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true )` " to the " `onCreate()` " method of " *Term_CourseSelection_Activity.java* " allowed the crash through clicking that "back" button.

I apologize in this last part because of my memory.  I had accidentally found a way for the "back" button to return to MainActivity directly, even when an Activity's parent did not exist as MainActivity.  I do not remember the details though.  Doing that also avoided the NullPointerException.